# Design pattern for editing list item

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a very basic app that reads an array json file and displays it to a recycler view.

I want to be able to modify one of these items but can think of multiple ways, none of which feel right.

It cannot be a new problem so I am asking if there is design pattern for just this case.

Currently i have my main Activity that shows the list.
If i press a list item, i navigate to an activity to show the item detail.
There is an edit button on this activity that leads to an Activity to edit the list item.
Once edited, it needs to be saved to the json file, and then calls the main activity that re-reads the json file and displays the items.

This feels very inefficient.

Appreciate any advice on how to improve this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change the list in the MainActivity by calling the adapter's         `notifyDataSetChanged()`, and save to JSON file in `onPause()` or `onStop()` method of the MainActivity. Because to my knowledge, I/O takes time therefore need to be minimized